# How to recreate a google compute engine vm from one project in another project?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have created a VM in project A in GCE. I want to create a new instance based on this VM in another project B.

I reckon I can spawn a new instance based on the a disk snapshot. However I cannot find any option to transfer such a snapshot across project.

My questions are:

1) how can I transfer a disk snapshot across projects in Google Cloud Platform projects?

2) Is there a better way to achieve this other than using a docker image?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since I cannot turn off the source VM because it is currently in use in a production environment, I have to use the following steps to create a mirror VM in another project:

1) Create a snapshot of the boot disk of the source VM

2) Create a disk based on this snapshot in the target project

```
 gcloud compute disks create vm-prod-disk --source-snapshot \
 https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/<source-\
 project>/global/snapshots/<source-vm-snapshot> --project target-project
```

3) Create a VM based on the new disk from step 2

```
gcloud compute instances create vm-prod-duplicate \
--project target-project --disk name=vm-prod-disk,boot=yes
```

Comment: Creating a snapshot of a running instance may result in an inconsistent snapshot.

Answer (score 4):

You first have to create an image in your `old-project`

```
gcloud compute images create "my-image" --source-disk "my-disk"
```

Now, you can create a machine in another project with it, since images are global resources:

```
gcloud compute instances create "my-instance" \
    --image "my-image" \
    --image-project "new-project"
```

There are also [other solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29585381/google-compute-engine-use-snapshot-from-another-project).

Comment: I tried the `image create` but it complaints about  `The disk resource 'my-disk' is already being used by 'my-vm'`

Comment: You first have to turn off the VM and detach the disk from the VM. After that you can reattach it again.

Comment: I see. Unfortunately I cannot turn off the vm instance. It is a production instance

Answer (score -1):

create an image in your old-project

```
    gcloud compute images create "my-image" --source-disk "my-disk"
```

copy image to new-project

```
    gcloud compute --project=newprojectid images create image-2 --source-image=image-1 --source-image-project=oldprojectid
```

create instance using this image

Comment: This is almost identical to the accepted answer, with the exception that it's less complete.